# How to prevent variable substitution in puppet-nginx module

Tags: nginx, puppet

Not 100% sure if this is a puppet question or module specific ([jfryman/puppet-nginx](https://github.com/jfryman/puppet-nginx)) but using this puppet code below, my goal is to preserve the variable $upstream that is written to the config file. However it is always substituted for the actual value. The reason for the substitution is detailed [here](http://tenzer.dk/nginx-with-dynamic-upstreams/)

```
$upstream = "http://acme.unix.local"
nginx::resource::vhost { 'acme.co':
  listen_port => 8080,
  server_name => [
    'www.acme.co'
  ],
  proxy => "$upstream", 
}
```

This is intended ,

```
location / {
  proxy_pass $upstream; 
}
```

Unfortunately I am getting this result ,

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://acme.unix.local;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use single quotes:

```
$upstream = "http://acme.unix.local"
nginx::resource::vhost { 'acme.co':
  listen_port => 8080,
  server_name => ['www.acme.co'],
  proxy       => '$upstream', 
}
```